# How do I determine the compile-time type of a TypeScript.Expression that is a function parameter?

Tags: typescript, tslint

When working with the TypeScript abstract syntax tree, how do I determine the compile-time type of a TypeScript.Expression that was supplied as a function parameter?

In the following code, I want to know the type of the parameter passed to setTimeout.

```
function invoke(functionArg : () => void) {
    setTimeout(functionArg);
}
```

The AST lines up like this:

```
setTimeout -> TypeScript.CallExpression
functionArg -> TypeScript.SyntaxKind.Identifier
```

I have tried several ways to get this info, but the TypeChecker keeps reporting the type as 'any'.

```
this.languageServices.getDefinitionAtPosition(...).kind     // yields 'parameter'
this.languageServices.getTypeDefinitionAtPosition(...).kind // yields ''
this.typeChecker.typeToString(...);                         // yields 'any'
this.typeChecker.getTypeAtLocation(...).flags               // yields any
this.typeChecker.getTypeAtLocation(...).symbol              // yields undefined
```

A node has a parent... and I could climb up the AST analyzing parent nodes until I find the correct definition. But this is a bad idea. There must be a simpler way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post a complete code example?

Comment: That is my complete code example. It is in file.ts. Would it matter if I put the function inside a class or module?

Comment: I'm asking for the code that's actually invoking the language service, not the code the LS is loading